# Gitlab on premise with Google OAuth2 error "Invalid grant: code was already redeemed"

Tags: oauth-2.0, omniauth, gitlab, google-oauth

Trying to install gitlab via docker http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/. Configured, started locally, added entry to /etc/hosts pointing domain to 127.0.0.1 to try it out. Everything works including google_oauth2 (thus app_id and app_secret are correct).

When moved to prod server with the SAME domain name got 500 from gitlab:

```
Could not authenticate you from GoogleOauth2 because "Invalid grant: code was already redeemed.
{
  "error" : "invalid grant",
  "error description" : "code was already redeemed."
}".
```

Also note I'm running gitlab behind https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/ both locally and on prod server.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured out this. The problem on prod server was in wrong datetime, ntp wasn't configured right.